# Populating Multiple Fields After Contenteditable Update

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server

I am using contenteditable on a large form with 1-unlimited rows/results from a php query. I need to update key input/contenteditable fields based values entered in other fields.

Here is the Script:

```
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
  $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
  $.ajax({
    url: "update_doors.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:'column='+column+'&editval='+encodeURIComponent($(editableObj).val())+'&id='+id,
    success: function(data){
      $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
      var description = data[0]; 
      var leaf = data[1];
      $('#description'+id).val(description);
      $('#leaf'+id).val(leaf);
    }
  });
}
```

Here is part of the html/php form:

```
<td class="center"><textarea id="description<?php echo $schedule_row['id']; ?>" contenteditable="true" onChange="saveToDatabase(this,'[Description]','<?php echo $schedule_row['id']; ?>')" onClick="editRow(this);" type="text" rows="1" style="width: 90%;" class="input-clearfit-left out"><?php echo $schedule_row['Description']; ?></textarea></td>
            <td class="center"><input id="leaf<?php echo $schedule_row['id']; ?>" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'[Leaf]','<?php echo $schedule_row['id']; ?>')" onClick="editRow(this);" type="text" value="<?php echo $schedule_row['Leaf']; ?>" class="input-clearfit"></td>
```

And here is the update query:

```
$editval = $_POST["editval"];

$column = $_POST["column"];

sqlsrv_query($conn, "UPDATE OE_Order_Entry_Detail SET " . $_POST["column"] . " = '".$editval."' WHERE  id = " . $_POST["id"]);

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT [Description], [Leaf] FROM OE_Order_Entry_Detail WHERE [id]=" . $_POST["id"]);
$array = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($array);
```

There are more fields in the form but the 2 primary's that I am looking to reload/refresh dynamically are the "description" and "leaf" columns which will have changed based on selections made in other columns/input fields within that row of data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've searched and tried numerous different solutions but have yet to find anything that functions properly without having to refresh the entire page in order to get the updated values.

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is wide open to sql injection. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Thanks Sean, but I pulled all of the "extra" coding out (ie. sanitize, etc) to just display the relevant coding.

Comment: My comment has nothing to do with code you pulled out. The code you posted is a textbook example of sql injection. Building up a string and executing it is a recipe for disaster. This issue should be far more pressing than the current challenge you are facing.